# The datediff function resulted in an overflow

Tags: t-sql

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND,DateTimeOn,DateTimeOff),0),     108)
```

The above query runs and brings back values but equally return the error:

"The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs when the dates are more than 68 years apart. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

> If the return value is out of range for int (-2,147,483,648 to
>   +2,147,483,647), an error is returned. For millisecond, the maximum difference between startdate and enddate is 24 days, 20 hours, 31
>   minutes and 23.647 seconds. For second, the maximum difference is 68
>   years.

You can solve it with a `case`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR,DateTimeOn,DateTimeOff) >= 68 THEN '>68 years'
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND,DateTimeOn,DateTimeOff),0),     108) END CASE
```